# Fill cylinder cap with quads

Tags: modeling, mesh, topology

Is there any way of converting the triangle fan found on a cylinder cap into quads.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you know that your circle has a even number of vertices, and do not care how the gird is aligned; then select all the vertices in the circle with <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>RMB [image: RMB]</kbd>, then <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd> > *grid fill*.

Select half of the vertices of the circle. The selection needs to have the same number of vertices along the top and bottom, and the same number unselected on the side.
[image: selection]

Then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd> > *grid fill*.
[image]

Which will give you this.  [image]

Comment: The number of selected vertices in one loop needs to be odd to.

Comment: @user877329 I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: I found that there was a vertex left in the middle that caused the operation to fail.

Comment: Grid Fill also works if you select the entire loop, but not if there is an odd number of vertices.  If the number is odd, it will give an error message saying "Select two Edge Loops."  Alt-V now adds the ability to quickly splice in the extra vert that is need, or instead, you could dissolve one vertex.

Comment: @MarcClintDion I edited my question just before you posted that!

Comment: Things often happen quick on this site.

Comment: @user877329 make sure there is no cap on the cylinder, it needs to be empty before you use the grid fill.

Answer (score 16):

If you intend to **subdivide** the mesh later (eg. using Subsurf modifier) and use only Grid Fill on the cap, you will get distorted mesh, despite the fact that it's all quads.

In such situations caring about all quad faces is not enough and filling the gap with simple Grid Fill operation won't do the trick. You need at least one additional edge loop on the cap before using Grid Fill, like the mesh on the right shows:

[image: distorted all quad mesh]

Answer (score 9):

<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> will convert triangles to quads where possible. For good topology and efficient geometry, you can use grid fill but then you should change the Span value to 1.

[image: Click for Larger Version]

Click the image see it at full size.
Current as of Blender 2.72b

Answer (score 2):

Keep the triangle fan and in edit mode dissolve every other edge to leave quads:

[image]

Comment: Interesting option! Mightn't be feasible always but definitely an option in some situations. You'd still end up with a pole at the centre though.