# Triangles to Quads Problem

Tags: modeling, topology

[image]

In the First-image, I fill the hole, then by default its looks triangulated

[image]

In the second image, now I want to make this into quads. So I have to do *Tries to quad* via <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>J</kbd> lets me do this.

In the last image it did not work completely, some tries are still tries. I tried to increase or decrease the angle property. But No solution found.

[image]

Comment: related http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/14580/1853

Comment: read also http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3199/weird-deformation-between-large-ngon-and-edge-ring/3204#3204

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Circles and Quads are always a strange mix.

You can use **Grid Fill** to get quads.

Go to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> or Mesh->Faces->Grid Fill on the menu. 
Or just press the space bar and type Grid Fill.

Pressing <kbd>F6</kbd> will bring out the different options for the tool (or you can set them on the Grid Fill tab that appears on the Left Side of the screen by pressing <kbd>T</kbd>)

[image]

**Other option** to deal with edges on a cylinder is  to select the edge, **extrude** (<kbd>E</kbd>) and **scale** to bring the edges in, then extrude again and press <kbd>Esc</kbd> without moving the mouse. Then just **merge** the edges at the center <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> into a pole. This oPtion will give you some triangles, but in a manageable topology.

[image]

**Other way** to deal with the issue is selecting the edge and using **Fill** <kbd>F</kbd>. That will create a **N-gon**.

Then you can use **inset** (<kbd>I</kbd>). To fill the center you can choose then between an N-gon (Using **fill** again) or triangles with a common pole.

[image]

Comment: Oao ! Thats nice, can you please tell me where this [Grid Fill] Menu Located ?

Comment: @cegaton i know spacebar command. But wanted to know the original menu located. thanks