# How to handle distortion at the poles of a UV sphere?

Tags: modeling, mesh, topology

I've been working on this helmet today just messing around, completely new to blender. I used a UV sphere to achieve the shape but its lead to an issue I don't know how to fix. I've tried cutting it, smoothing it, adding subdivisions and nothing has removed this. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Here is my problem]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is just to add extra supporting geometry around that part:

[image]

Another way is to use a [quad-based style of cap](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/28963/599):

[image]

[image]