# remove poles from sphere?

Tags: modeling, wireframe

[image]

hello is it possible to remove these poles on the wireframe and somehow structure the wireframe differently? ive tried deleting faces but it still draws the looks to the pole of the modelled sphere.
my aim is to have the object in a wireframe but have it look even and smooth without drawing the viewers eye to one part of the object.
does anyone know something?

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE. Here's a possibly related question: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70810/how-to-avoid-the-wrinkle-at-the-poles-of-the-uv-sphere/70862#70862: see if it can help.

Answer (score 2):

Use the "Remesh" modifier.
Play with the settings until you get the level of detail that you want.

Comment: thank you so much! i thought i'd have to do it all again