# Toon material present some kind of deformation, jagged, spike noise

Tags: shadows, noise-reduction

1. Please take a look at the images and tell me if there are any way to have a perfect transition between colors and get rid of that noise marked in the last image.
2. There is a way to make that plane receive the sphere shadow with the plane's darker color (dark pink)? The way it is now, the sphere has no projected shadow.

(I created the plane's material the same way I created the sphere, but with just two color instead of four)

[image: The sphere material]

[image: The problem is marked here]

Comment: could you add a foto in edit mode?

Comment: Since I'm new here, I can add just two images... https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwPbYi5oecLWUWo2SEEwT3RPQUk

Comment: Sorry then. We may assume your mesh does not have any irregularities at this spot? Does the same error occur from different angles, and at the same spot on the surface? Or at the same point in your rendered image (a bit below the top point)?

Comment: Is just a simple UV Sphere with modifier subdivision set to 3. I think that noise is related to the light angle. https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwPbYi5oecLWajd4MnhRcEJxWGM https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwPbYi5oecLWOHhPX2l6Vk5GWVE

Comment: Another exemple moving the light https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwPbYi5oecLWanEwMXAzTGNKM2M https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwPbYi5oecLWRkQwOUNBTUMyZDg

Comment: I believe it's the pole of the UV Sphere (where all the lines join at a single point) and it is affecting the smooth shading. Try replacing it with an Icosphere which should not have the same problem as each face will be better proportioned and similarly sized (rather than having long thin triangles).

Comment: You probably have some wrinkles at the pole of the UV Sphere. This may help you to solve it: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70810/how-to-avoid-the-wrinkle-at-the-poles-of-the-uv-sphere

Comment: I'm giving up. I'll try another way to create this toon visual. I follow the suggestions from Rich Sedman and Paul Gonet: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwPbYi5oecLWSUhfaFRqdmJsUnM

Comment: @FernandoRosa For the icosphere in your example, is that set to Smooth Shading? It looks like flat shading to me. Click Smooth and see if that helps.

Comment: @Rick Sedman you are right, it isn't set to smooth. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by the geometry at the pole of the UV Sphere interacting with the Smooth Shading to produce artifacts in the generated Normal as described in this question and its associated answers : [How to avoid the wrinkle at the poles of the UV sphere?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70810/how-to-avoid-the-wrinkle-at-the-poles-of-the-uv-sphere)

The UV Sphere consists of edges formed from the Latitudinal lines (those around the sphere) and the Longitudinal lines (those going north to south). The Longitudinal lines all converge at the poles and this creates a number of long thin triangle faces as shown :

[image: UV Sphere Pole]

The problem is that slight inaccuracies in the smooth shading of each adjacent face is resulting in noticeable artifacts in your toon shader.

You can avoid this problem by changing the geometry to avoid such long thin triangular faces. The attached answers provide some methods of achieving this but an alternative is to use an Ico Sphere in place of a UV Sphere.

The geometry of an Ico Sphere is made up by subdividing an Icosahedron (a 20-sided regular mesh) such that each face is an equilateral triangle. As there is no 'pole' to provide difficult geometry you should no longer get the issue.

Once you have created the Ico Sphere you can adjust the number of sub-divisions to determine the level of detail.

[image: icosphere]

Setting the mesh to Smooth Shading should produce a consistently smooth sphere.

For the shadows you could simply use the Shadow output of the existing Lamp Data node as the factor to a MixRGB node set to Multiply by a light grey (vary the intensity of this grey to affect the density of the shadow) as shown :

[image: shadows]