# Mesh meeting in the center

Tags: mesh

I'm sure it's easy to google, but I have no idea how to phrase it to find it.
I'm super new to blender and trying to model a spoon, and this is where I'm stuck:
[image]

[image]

How do I get rid of this? I tried doing a loop cut, I tried removing every other edge inside, so I get 4 corners instead of 3 - it only seems to make it worse.
Any tips for a beginner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick answer: you need to inset a little more and be sure that the last inset is planar to the center of your mesh.

Long answer: you need to fix your topology --> You can check here for more info on this problem: [How to avoid the wrinkle at the poles of the UV sphere?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70810/how-to-avoid-the-wrinkle-at-the-poles-of-the-uv-sphere)

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Triangle fan is not needed to achieve round shapes. Use 4-sided faces whenever possible. Try something like this:

[image]

You can also add Subdivision modifier at early design stage to see how the shape is rounded nicely even with low amount of faces.

Comment: Yeah, that's solution for if I would model something like this again, but I needed a solution for this mesh :) But I already got one. thanks anyway.