# How to make the mesh smooth

Tags: modeling

How can make the mesh smooth. With the mirror and subsurf modifier i want to have a round smooth sphere shape at the end. **Note : I dont want to apply the modifier**

[image]

**Edit mode**

[image]

**Object Mode**

[image]

Any solution or suggestion to end the verts to get smooth shape.

Comment: Subdivide it a couple of times and crank the smoothness up to 1.

Comment: The edge loop in the middle is the culprit, start by scaling that up and pulling it forward so the overall mesh is rounder. It also doesn't help that you have n-gons, it's generally recommending to use quads when possible.

Comment: @TheTrueJard so how can i end up then

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1684/what-is-the-technical-difference-between-an-ngon-and-a-bunch-of-triangles/1697#1697 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70810/how-to-avoid-the-wrinkle-at-the-poles-of-the-uv-sphere/70811#70811 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3199/why-does-subsurf-modifier-cause-weird-deformation-at-the-end-of-a-cylinder

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos. But its not working with my mesh. Reason its having mirror and subsurf modifier and that i dont want to apply it. It work on without modifiers. Thanks