# Texture is pinching and artifacting on the rounded edges of a mesh

Tags: texturing

I have been designing easter eggs to be 3D printed with pattern textures on them and I have stumbled across an issue when adding a texture to the egg model. As you can see there are a lot of artifacts and pinching on the rounded corners. Is this due to the mesh not being uniform with quads?

Thank you very much in advance for your assistance.

[image: Rounded Object Pinching, Artifacts]

Comment: hello, it is rather a topology issue, please show the topology in wireframe mode, you probably need to clean that in Edit mode, see here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70810/how-to-avoid-the-wrinkle-at-the-poles-of-the-uv-sphere ...  or do it in Sculpt mode as it looks like your topology is high-poly

Comment: @moonboots Thank you very much, I appreciate this.

Comment: in Sculpt mode you could enable Dyntopo and use the Smooth brush, but it looks like you've sculpted a texture? So maybe use it for the pole as well?

Comment: @moonboots This was done through the Displace modifier, adding a texture through there. Smooth brush causes it to crash Blender unfortunately.

Comment: oh ok so you should improve the pole topology instead

Comment: @moonboots I shall give it a shot, thank you again for the link and advice.

Answer (score 0):

**Intro**

Spheres can be generated with multiple approaches. Every approach has its down- and upsides. It depends what you are trying to achieve.

---

**Sphere from Primitive Sphere**

The problem here is the vertex on top. [image]

After applying subdivision you will get some interesting topology, looks cool but it's maybe not what you are looking for. I call it the tomato topology.

[image]

---

**Sphere from Icosphere**

Subdivision can be done while you enter parameters for the icosphere. There will not be a tomato topology. But there is a catch, you can't do loopcuts nor loopselections. Also it can cause problems if you use it with boolean modifier. Short: The triangle faces are causing issues down the line.

[image]

---

**Sphere from Cube**

With this approach you will be able to have quad topology without tomatos.
Loop selection is also possible.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this approach, much appreciated.