# Looking for help with procedural materials and "polar pinch"

Tags: baking, procedural

I've been playing around with making procedural planets in Blender 2.8. I was hoping to create the materials and export them to use in Three.js.

Creating the material was simple enough, but the only way I could think of to export the material was to bake the texture.
Everything looked fine in Blender, but in three.js the texture is pinched at the poles.

Is baking and saving the image the best way to go about this? Or does anyone have an idea on how to fix this issue?
This is what planet looked like in Blender:
[image]

And this is what it looks like in Three.js: Kinda hard to see the pinch with the blue, but you can see the green land masses being pulled toward to center.
[image]

For what it's worth, this is what the exported texture looks like. I'm assuming the dots alone the top and bottom are because I did not UV unwrap before I baked the texture. But even after doing it and UV unwrapping, the pinch was still there.

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid the wrinkle at the poles of the UV sphere?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70810/how-to-avoid-the-wrinkle-at-the-poles-of-the-uv-sphere)

Comment: Thanks. I'll give this a shot.