# I have a problem with the shading of the glass in my glasses

Tags: mesh

So I am trying to make my glasses, the lenses have a mirror coat. The problem is when I add a material, as we see on the right lens, is that we ca see the triangle shading happening. The lens are not completely flat, they are a tiny bit round.

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3199/why-does-subsurf-modifier-cause-weird-deformation-at-the-end-of-a-cylinder https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70810/how-to-avoid-the-wrinkle-at-the-poles-of-the-uv-sphere

Comment: I guess it has to do with your topology, you have stretched triangles, try to add edge loops to see if it gives a better result?