# How to remove / reduce wrinkle after adding subdivision surface modifier?

Tags: modifiers, subdivision-surface

I'm a beginner at blender . I added subdivision surface modifier to my object and chosen the Catmull-Clark . In my tutorial there is no wrinkle on the object , but for a reason i don't know there is a wrinkle on my object. The wrinkle does not appear on other part of the object , only on one specific area .

How do i remove the wrinkle ?

Before and after adding subdivision surface modifier :
[image]
[image]

With shading set to smooth , the wrinkle still visible :
[image]

Edit : here is my blend file
[image] (uploaded at https://blend-exchange.com/)

Comment: Do you know how to add loop-cuts (Ctrl-R) and insets (I) ?

Comment: Yes , these are on Mesh Tools available on Edit Mode.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70810/how-to-avoid-the-wrinkle-at-the-poles-of-the-uv-sphere https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1684/what-is-the-technical-difference-between-an-ngon-and-a-bunch-of-triangles https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3199/why-does-subsurf-modifier-cause-weird-deformation-at-the-end-of-a-cylinder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original structure:

[image]

Now, you can add one loop cut and one inset in the following manner:

[image]

Then increase the subsurf resolution to 5 or 6, then you get this:

[image]

If you still want the original *bends* in the stick-structure, you can add 2 loop cuts for each bend like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks , although i previously state i wanted round edge , i could just do this and make round edge afterward .

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your mesh by adding edge loops and removed the wrinkles.

Here is the file https://blend-exchange.com/b/OZnLl2AZ

To remove your wrinkles and also curving the top of your mesh

### STEP 1

You can start of by insetting the top face by selecting your face and pressing <kbd>I</kbd> on your keypad. So that you have something like this.

[image]

### STEP 2

Now select the edge loop closest to the top face and press <kbd>G</kbd> twice on your keypad to *edge slide* and bring the edge loop down so that it makes the top curved and circular like you asked for.

[image]

### STEP 3

Now *inset* the top face again

[image]

and then *edge slide* the loop again by pressing <kbd>G</kbd> twice on your keypad.

[image]

### STEP 4

The last step is to tab into object mode select your apple stem and then <kbd>Right-Click</kbd> *shade smooth* Also I  strongly recommend that you should make a few tweaks and adjustments to your mesh by just going around and selecting edge loops and *rotating** and *scaling* them.