how to remove creases on circle mesh while using subdivision modifier
I'm using subdivision modifier on my mesh but there are some creases on it.


if I use inset or loop cut, it'll lose its circularity.
how to remove these creases?

Hello what do you mean when you say that you'll loose circularity?

Hello, I mean, it creates a flat surface at the top, not completely flat but its noticeable.

You need to inset but move up a bit the inset

Yes, i tried that too, it'll make smaller creases but not removed.

Hello, KMD, welcome to BSE. I think this is a  duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70810/how-to-avoid-the-wrinkle-at-the-poles-of-the-uv-sphere , and quite a few others like it. Depending an how your spherical element is supposed to interact with the rest of your model, bear in mind as an option you can spherify any topology with a Cast modifier or 'To Sphere' operator.Technically, this post should close as a duplicate, but I see a discussion has started, so will hold off.

Thank you for your kind answer.

Inset several times the top face of your sphere A, create a sphere B (a default UV Sphere) at the exact same location that you rotate 90° on X, give it a Subdivision Surface with a level of 4, give your sphere A a Shrinkwrap modifier, that you put over its Subdivision Surface modifier, with sphere B as Target, it will make its surface stick to sphere B, apply the modifier:

Another solution would be to use another topology, like the ones here as suggested by Robin Betts, or subdivise a cube with a Smoothness of 1, or fill the top with a quad topology, etc:


The mesh A is not only a sphere, its a chess bead. When I set sphere B as target it removes the rest of the mesh.

You can choose a vertex group only

So, it just moves creases to sides of the mesh? Now I have 2 creases at both sides.

I'm not sure what you mean, could you please share your file? Also, you could use another topology than tris at the top

I mean, by rotating 90 degree of the sphere and using shrink, it removes top creases, but now I have 2 creases at both sides which belongs to Sphere B.
by creating multiple inset it will make the first crease less visible, But I just wondered if it can be removed completely.

And also by using another mesh for shrink, makes a undesirable cut between them,

Again, you can apply the Shrinkwrap on a vertex group only, or see my edit, you can use another topology instead of radial triangles, please share the object so that we can give a try

Hi, @moonboots .. holding off closing this as a dupe of https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70810/how-to-avoid-the-wrinkle-at-the-poles-of-the-uv-sphere and others like it.. but don't want to slam into this discussion.  KMD, if any of the linked answers are satisfactory, we should close this out.

Yes I also thought it was a duplicate but I couldn't find the answer you linked

@moonboots, thanks.. we'll just give KMD some space, as a new arrival :)
