# How to smooth a curved surface without it looking like a paper plate?

Tags: modeling

I have always had issues with curved surfaces, like the foot of a wine glass, for instance, but I have found that with smoothing them, it makes them to look like either a pancake or a paperplate, here is a fine example of this cylinder that I used the subserf modifier on:

[image: Smooth Faces]

It's just a simple cylinder:
[image]

And when I subsurf it, it makes like these ridges in the middles of what would be the tris.
[image]
[image]

Comment: I guess it's a problem of topology, you need to add some edge loops close to the edges so that it eliminate these artifacts, maybe show your topology in wireframe, or share your file?

Comment: It is literally just a cylinder that is subsurfed. It may be the topology. I have never considered loop cutting the flat edges of the circles.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41885/how-to-handle-distortion-at-the-poles-of-a-uv-sphere

Comment: See also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82477/cylinder-has-small-wierd-bumps-when-using-subdivision-surface?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Yes, it turns out this was a duplicate--avoiding the wrinkling at the  poles of a sphere. The topology was the problem. I went back this time with a square plane, extruded it out and and subdivid-smoothed the center and then used the subsurf modifier and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

You will automatically have these artifacts with this kind of topology (if you leave the top without any edge loop along the rim), because the subsurf won't leave enough faces to interpolate correctly between the slice and the top. So create a bevel or at least an inset to fix the problem:

[image]

Comment: While this is a fine answer, and I do like that you explained that that is a natural problem with the topology, that is not the kind of shape I wanted to make.

Comment: I've added 2 pictures, for something flatter, same thing, you need to add some edge loops, at least one.