# Is modeling something with an N-gon cap acceptable (i.e cylinders, cones etc.)

Tags: modeling

I've seen tutorials where people will take a cylinder with an n-gon cap for the top and bottom while the middle portion has a bunch of subdivisions. I've seen people use these to model cups, mugs, poles, etc., but I was told and taught that N-gons were not okay. Would something like this merely be the exception to the rule. After all it's an option in both Maya and Blender, so if it wasn't acceptable I wouldn't expect it to even be an option. I'm searching for opinions/answers to this.

Comment: There is no real rule. It all comes down to what the purpose of the mesh/object is. All objects get rendered as triangles, sometimes ngons will result in unexpected subdivisions or otherwise irregular surfaces when subdivided or deformed. Topology based on quads will give you more predictable and controllable results.

Comment: Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/133797/how-to-smooth-a-curved-surface-without-it-looking-like-a-paper-plate and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6425/keep-sharp-edges-when-using-subdivision-surface and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/734/how-to-smooth-shade-an-object-while-retaining-hard-edges

Comment: If the purpose of your model is that of a cylinder with flat caps and it stays within Blender for rendering, then it should be OK. In many other cases, it's debatable. In any case, it's not a big deal to fill the caps with either triangles or quads. Blender (and possibly many other 3D modelling suites) has the n-gon option, because it leaves the choice to the users, instead of patronizing them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think I've found the best method and that would be to just have the tops have intersections. The reason why is because when you smooth it, it will become all quads, which is not something that will happen when you smooth a cylinder with a flat top. Thank you everyone.