# How to close this hole with clean geometry?

Tags: modeling, topology

I modelled a set of plates and bowls, all based on one design - see renders and the attached blend (one plate). It's a design choice that all the items have geometry slightly bunched up on the outer rim, it is necessary to get a nice subtle wavy decoration on the plates and bowls. But the problem is the center of every plate and bowl. I have a large hole and I can't find a clean way to close it, clean meaning good geometry, quads only and all evenly spaced. I made 3 attempts. One is using an N-gon, least work, but it renders badly, its triangulated and it's a visible flaw in the render. Two other attempts were done using the Grid Fill function, one regular and one with Simple Deform checked. It looks ok with subdivision level 0, but its bad when subdivided, at least I think so. It looks bad, it's uneven, and there are faces bunching up near the edges of the hole.

Please note, that the outer geometry is bunched up on 3 sides, on purpose, there are more edge loops in these areas.

Can someone have a look into this? I'm attaching the blend. How to get good geometry, a nice evenly spaced closing for this gap, quads only?

[image: Attempt 1 - Level 0][image: Attempt 1 - Level 2][image: Attempt 2 - Level 0][image: Attempt 2 - Level 2][image: Attempt 3 - Level 0][image: Attempt 3 - Level 2]

[image]

Comment: take a look at this answer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/29086/7777

Comment: Method 1 works fine.  The only way to get a perfectly spaced grid is to move all the vertices around the edge of the center section to be evenly spaced.  I don't see any egregious artifacts when rendering your blend file so I don't know what problem you are trying to solve.