# Continuing division of cylinder to top faces

Tags: modeling

I have a cylinder that I made and the scaled the top faces down to make it more barrel shaped, and I colored in part of it, and I would like the top faces to divide the same way the body does, so 32 segments and have it divide up until the center, I tried to figure this out but am struggling to find a way that isn't difficult, though I'm sure there is an easy way. Here's a picture with a very poor drawing to hopefully help clarify what I'm asking. Thanks!

I would like it to continue the divisions up like how I have (poorly) drawn, all around the cylinder, on both top and bottom faces
[image]

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6425/keep-sharp-edges-when-using-subdivision-surface and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28963/what-are-the-benefits-of-the-different-cylinder-caps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a face, select it in Edit mode, then type Alt-P (Poke).  Another method which works with or without a face: select the face or edge loop, extrude it in place (E then Escape), then type Alt-M (Merge).  For your purposes you probably want to merge "at center" or "collapse" but there are other options that might be useful.

Comment: This works but seems to create way to many sections. How do I get it to be the same amount of vertices that I have on my cylinder

Comment: It is hard to say without seeing your object.  These methods will create as many sections as there are vertices around the relevant edge loop or face.  If you're getting extra sections, I assume it's because you have extra vertices for some reason.

Comment: I can make an edit to my post and show what it looks like if I do it your way if that would help

Comment: Nevermind actually, if I do that before scaling down the faces to make them smaller, it works perfectly. I just have to do that first and scale it second, thank you!