# Modelling Sphere Pole

Tags: mesh

I've applied smooth shading and auto smooth to this sphere shape, and when I apply the subsurface modifier I'm getting artefacts on top of the sphere. Ive tried adding loop cuts, and also deleted the top faces and did a grid fill but only made it worse. How can I fix the sphere not to have that weird pinching on the top?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3199/why-does-subsurf-modifier-cause-weird-deformation-at-the-end-of-a-cylinder

Comment: Hello :). These threads should help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/70810/, https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/28963/