# How to divide a circle into a square grid?

Tags: edit-mode

How can I divide a circle into a square grid? Think of the subdivision of a plane, but with a circular border. It should look something like this, just imagine that the circle select cursor is the border:

[image]

I searched everywhere for an answer, but I could not find any.
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14579/fill-cylinder-cap-with-quads/14580#14580 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16043/triangles-to-quads-problem/16044#16044

Comment: @cegaton they are not related as I want a perfect square grid, not a deformed square grid like in those questions.

Comment: May I ask why you need such a grid without caring about proper topology?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is how I do it:
[image: gridify circle]

1. Create a circle and put it a little over the grid plane;
2. In *Object* mode select the circle first, then add the plane to the selection, by pressing <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> (the order is important);
3. Go to top view (<kbd>Numpad 7</kbd>) in *Orthographic View* (toggle with <kbd>Numpad 5</kbd>);
4. Go in *Edit* mode with <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd>;
5. Be sure to have all the meshes selected (hit <kbd>A</kbd>);
6. In the <kbd>T</kbd> panel (or just by searching with <kbd>Space</kbd>) find *Knife project* and click it.
7. Invert the selection with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>
8. Delete the selected mesh parts with <kbd>X</kbd>.

Like LukeD said in another answer, this causes your mesh to have a mix of ngons, quads and tris, but that's what you asked for in your question. :-)

Comment: This looks like the answer I'm looking for. I'll try it.

Comment: Also I don't care about the ngons and tris in the edges because I'm not going to modify them. I'm only going to modify the quads.

Answer (score 1):

You can do with the F2 Addon
Select 2 vertex and press f to make a edge
Then Press F to make vertical edges same with the horizontal edges
[image]

Comment: Why did you double my answer?

Comment: actually i answered and did not refresh somebody answered it after refresh my answer was below yours sorry

Comment: You can just delete it to not make it a mess here.

Comment: The results don't look at all the same.

Comment: @StarWeaver I did not get what you mean

Comment: Despite the final result looks like a grid, the horizontal and vertical edges built with this approach are disjoined: you are building two overlapping sets of faces. Perhaps it would be better to finish with Vertex Connect Path tool or something in order to truly subdivide the edges.

Comment: I did that with the knife but soon realised that it is not a perfect square grid.

Comment: @Tooniis what useful answer you like so that you can vote that person