# How to regular-subdivide an irregular edged flat surface in Blender

Tags: modeling, objects

I want to break a surface into pieces of square shapes like in the image below. How do I do that?

The blue is a mesh surface with one face (object) and the squares are a subdivided mesh.

[image: Lake object]
Thanks

Comment: Is the blue shape an object or a background image?

Comment: The blue is a mesh object (face). The lines are also a subdivided plane.

Comment: Does this help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91158/how-to-divide-a-face-into-a-square-grid/91162#91162

Comment: Thank you Ray. it was a great help. I am not just that pro in Blender, but I am getting there.

Comment: Ray - When I did the knief project tool, the cust through was not as perfect. Any idea?

Comment: @Farsh please add images that illustrate what happened when you tried knife project. What exactly do you mean with "was not perfect".