# Auto-Generate Mesh Grid from Contour

Tags: mesh, workflow, cloth-simulation

I'm currenlty working with this free 3d cloth modeling addon (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jNXBYI-WPU4), it is similar to Marvelous Designer, even though short on features.

One problem is the creation of an evenly spaced mesh used for the cloth.

A way to tackle this problem is to create a grid mesh with only edges and no faces. Fill the contour with faces and do a Knife Projection from the grid edge mesh onto the contour.

[image]

This way I do gain a mesh with evenly spaced faces, however this workflow is quite cumbersome if the contour needs to change.

**Therefore my question is: Is it possible to auto generate a mesh grid from a given contour in a non-destructive way?**

Optimally the mesh would regenerate if the contour changes.

Comment: If you quote an answer to another question, feel free to give the link, it could be useful (as well to answer you as for those who are looking for something similar) https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/152898/55910

Comment: You are right! Here it is: [how-to-divide-a-face-into-a-square-grid](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91158/how-to-divide-a-face-into-a-square-grid)