# How To Divide A Mesh Into Circular Pattern with Perfect Squares

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, edit-mode, subdivision-surface

[image]

How can I divide my mesh circle  like the picture? I can use inset to do it with lines going from boundary to the centre but how the add the circular divisions?

Comment: maybe related? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16043/triangles-to-quads-problem/16044#16044

Comment: Ctrl + R = Loop Subdivide could be what you want? https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.81/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/loop.html

Comment: You could just get a add uv sphere. Delete vertices to get one hemisphere.  Then scale on a axis (Z) to zero.  You can flatten half a sphere.

Comment: select the edges in the midle, and subdivide. Also you should use poke faces instead of inset.

Comment: Please define "Perfect square" : by the nature of what you are asking, you can't have perfect squares because the side closest to the center of the disc will always be smaller than the other side. Also the "squares" will be more and more skewed when you get closer to the center

Answer (score 2):

Just to illustrate *@Alex*'s comment. You can simply subdivide the inner edges.

1. Select the inner edges
2. Go *Edge > Subdivide*
3. Adjust to your liking

[image]

Comment: thank u so much!

Comment: Perhaps a "dartboard" describes the result desired, as opposed to "perfect squares".  @MuhammadBinAslam if this has answered your question please consider accepting.

Comment: Note that there is a big difference between a square and a trapezoid.

Comment: @batFINGER you are quite right. thanks