# Applied a subdivision modifier and imported in Substance Painter 2, the result is horrible

Tags: materials, uv, subdivision-surface

I made this model in Blender. This is the low poly model:
[image]

And this is high poly. I added a subdivision modifier and applied it. You can see that the UV map actually updated as well:

[image]

And this is when I imported it in Substance Painter 2. I exported model as .FBX:
[image]

As you can see, the bottom part is horrible. I just want to render it clearly, but you can see that some kind of zig-zag lines in the model.

I adjusted the tolerance and hardness parameters but it doesn't seem to work.

How do I get a clean result when exporting the high-poly version where the subdivision surface modifier has been applied?

Comment: You extruded and scaled in those edges on the bottom but then you finished it off with an ngon.  Extrude it once or twice more and do a Grid Fill at the center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get all the faces that are meant to be flat together as one face. The bottom face on the cylinder in your case should look like a flat face, but because it's made out of a lot of faces, it doesn't. 
Select one of the bottom faces:
[image: Select]

press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to select all the faces that are on a 0 degree angle of it:
[image: Select] 
Now hit <kbd>X</kbd> and choose 'Dissolve faces'. Now you have erased the unnecessary vertices:
[image: X]
[image: Delete]

Comment: This is perfect. Everything is now go fine! Thanks!!!!

Comment: This is not very perfect as using Ngons can be a problem by itself. It's better to avoid Ngons before subdividing in the first place, if editing afterwards then fill the area with quads.

Comment: Then tell me: How do you want to make a circular face out of just quads?

Comment: Simple - filling with quads. See [fill cylinder cap with quads](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14579/fill-cylinder-cap-with-quads). Ngons are in most cases draft modeling which should be avoided in the final result.

Comment: that also gives a few weird results on the side of the mesh. If it's just about taking away those lines, ngons are no problem. Filling with quads has no need in this question and so my answer is correct.