# How to add faces to a cylinder top? (cookie)

Tags: modeling, mesh, faces

I am an absolute beginner, and while completing the donut tutorial I have been trying to model this industrial cookie just for fun.

[image: Model image]

I have modeled the top cookie as a cylinder, beveled the edge and extruded it to create the border, and added a couple of loop cuts to sharpen rounded angles, and I am at this stage:

[image: My model]

Now I would like to sculpt the "shield" (and then carve holes and add text), but the center face has not enough resolution. How can I add enough poligons into that face so that sculpt works?

Comment: Hello :). This looks like a job for the [Grid Fill](https://docs.blender.org/manual/fr/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/face/grid_fill.html) function.

Comment: Thank you Jachym!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you I would make the text apart, you won't notice it's another mesh, or join it with the rest with some tris. I would just model the ornement then join with the outer circle:

[image]

Comment: *This Moonboots uses cookies*  `Accept ✓` / `Refuse ✕` :)

Comment: ah ah I even eat them  ;)

Comment: How umiliating!!!! :-D
It's wonderful.. Yes I already had the idea of creating the curved text as a separate element (though, I want it "rounded" as i goes up, not with so sharp edges), but... that's the only thing I sort of know how to achieve.

How did you model the ornament? I see you created some poligons "in the big empty area of the cylinder cap", but I don't know how to do that...
You then extruded them (and that is ok), and then "joined" the new faces with the existing ones... This also is something I don't know how to create.

Comment: Oh! And... you didn't carve holes in the cookie, did you? I think the chocolate cream splotches are that big on purpose. :-P

Comment: yes I dug some holes with extrusions. To fill the inner circle you need to follow the shapes of ornement, then fill the faces. Maybe you should follow some tutos on how reduce topology like this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HGL6QpVRyXk  or https://topologyguides.com/  If you don't want sharp edge, create bevels and move the edge loops so it doesn't sharp the edges.

Comment: and don't cook the chocolate with the biscuit or it will melt

Comment: Thanks, will do! At the moment I can't say I understand this last answer because what I do not know is how (which keys and commands) I can create new poligons in the cylinder cap... Unless what you did was to grid fill the whole part and then moving the verteces to mimic the ornament...
But if not, I guess the tutorial you linked will explain everything, thanks!

Comment: no grid fill in my case, only edge extrusions, fill edges or faces, knife tool, join vertices... if you don't know all this, maybe follow some very basic tutorials, like Grant Abbit or else...

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, that face should reassemble a grid made out of quads (polygons of 4 vertices) so that when you sculpt it, the resolution is more or less equal along the entire mesh

The fastest way to do so would be to delete that big face on the middle, selecting the edge loop (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd>) corresponding to the face you just deleted and in the face properties menu (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) selecting the option "Grid Fill". If the results are not what's expected, in the redo menu (the small popup that appears after you perform an action on the bottom right of the screen) are some options to adjust the algorithms response.

In classic stackexchange/overflow I will refer you to an older [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14579/fill-cylinder-cap-with-quads)  and the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/fr/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/face/grid_fill.html) that explain this exact function in a more graphic way.

If you are a beginner this is the simplest yet more correct way i can think of to set you up and running. As you keep learning you will probably need to find more appropriate ways to correctly preparing your mesh for modelling or whatever,providing you with the best results. One step at a time.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I could correctly subdivide the face but, as you anticipated, this is not enough for my sculpting need because I selected too little faces and verteces, and therefore when I create a grid it is not enough "detailed", each generated face is still too big and so, not practically sculptable...
In the end I settled for a "remesh" modifier, which I suspect would be a problem to carve the holes for the chocolate cream, but... I don't know how to drill the holes yet. Way to go!
Anyway, thank you for the valuable information!