# Best way to model this smiley face tablet

Tags: modeling, modifiers, sculpting

I'm a complete beginner trying to model this smiley face tablet (image attached). I tried using a cylinder for the tablet and then sculpting the eyes and mouth. Also tried using boolean difference modifier for the eyes (don't know if I can do that for the mouth as well). I'm just curious if there's a better way to do this. Sculpting works okay but it also seems like it's done manually (the shapes don't look very accurate). Thanks you!!

[image: Smiley face pill]

Comment: Relared: [How to add faces to a cylinder top](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/177737/78972)

Comment: draw the face, then extrude outward and make a circle with the extrusion, then extrude to give thickness

Comment: @moonboots thanks but I'm not sure what draw the face means. How can I draw free form with blender? Are you talking about curves? Sorry I'm an absolute beginner (just finished the donut tutorial)

Comment: look at the page linked by Jachym, you need to use your picture as a background blueprint and follow the shape of the face with some vertices, then fill the gap with the outer circle, then extrude down to give thickness