# How to fix pinched circular faces?

Tags: modeling

I created some office chair wheels and would like to grab the following face and expand it out so that it's not completely flat.

[image]

Upon expanding, the face becomes pinched like so.

[image]

[image]

I tried using inset (Ctrl + I) but it would flatten out the face. Is there any way to fix the pinch while maintaining the expanded face?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3199/why-does-subsurf-modifier-cause-weird-deformation-at-the-end-of-a-cylinder https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1684/what-is-the-technical-difference-between-an-ngon-and-a-bunch-of-triangles https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14579/fill-cylinder-cap-with-quads